# API call link in angular not calling API but created link works in postman

Tags: angular, typescript, api, entity-framework-core

I'm making an app for a bootcamp where I call a third party API to get dog breeds, then I use 2 created apis to store users and the users favorites to 2 SQL database created with EF. I have an Angular front end that is where all of these will interact.

I'm trying to take a user object I've created out of a modal form and put it in one of my SQL databases using an api call from an API I've created expecting a user object.

In the dev tools I see it getting up to creating the link string, meaning the object is created, and all the paramaters have been added, but the API call doesn't happen and it doesnt post to the database.

Also if I copy and paste that linkstring into my API in postman it correctly adds the user to the database, but the API call just doesn't seem to want to post it to my database.

My relevant code is as follows. Any help is vastly appreciated

**front end**

**user interface**

```
export interface IUser{
    Id?: number
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
    email: string
    password: string
}
```

**api.service.ts**

```
export class ApiService {
  private breedUri = 'https://dog-breeds2.p.rapidapi.com/dog_breeds';
  private userApi ='https://localhost:7078/api/Users';
  private faveApi ='https://localhost:7078/api/FavoriteBreeds';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  addUser(newUser: IUser){

   const linkString = (this.userApi+"/add?firstName="+newUser.firstName+"&lastName="+newUser.lastName+"&email="+newUser.email+"&password="+newUser.password)

    console.log("user api link created",{linkString})
   return this.http.post(this.userApi +"/add", newUser)
   
  }
```

**method in app.component.ts**

```
    constructor(private api: ApiService){}

    addNewUser(){
        this.addform = document.getElementById('loginForm');
        const formData = new FormData(this.addform);

      let newUser: IUser = {
       
        firstName: formData.get("firstName") as string,
        lastName: formData.get("lastName") as string,
        email: formData.get("email") as string,
        password: formData.get("psw") as string
       };
          console.log("user object being created check", {newUser})
          this.api.addUser(newUser);

      }
```

**backend**

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class UsersController : Controller
  {
    UsersRepository repo=new UsersRepository();

    [HttpPost("add")]
    public Users AddNewUser(Users newUser)
    {

      return repo.AddNewUser(newUser);
    }
```

[my devtools showing the link and created user object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xgdu.png)
[my swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fheNw.png)

Comment: Don't think SQL server is relevant to the question if it works via postman

Comment: Aside... JavaScript, TypeScript and JSON are case-sensitive. `Id` is a different property than `id`, but shouldn't matter in this case because it's probably null and so doesn't get serialized in the post body. (You could confirm that via the Network tab in Dev Tools, checking what content body got posted.)

Comment: sql server is how im storing the user, and the id is only there cause i have the id in the backend im pretty sure i can delete it and it will serve the same purpose, i just have it in as null in case its needed for like association purposes as my user model in my backend has an id attribute that is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this line:

```
return this.http.post(this.userApi +"/add", newUser)
```

It returns an Observable. Observable is only triggered when it is subscribed. Thus, without subscribing, your Angular side didn't send the request to API. You can determine whether the request is sent by checking the browser DevTools --> Network tab and searching the request based on your API URL to be submitted.

You need to subscribe to the `Observable` and provide the observer to handle the returned Observable value (response) by scenario (success/error callback).

```
addNewUser(){

  ...

  this.api.addUser(newUser).subscribe({
    next: (response: any) {
      // TO-DO: Handling when the response is succeed
    },
    error: (err: any) {
      // TO-DO: Handling when the response is failed
    },
    complete: () {
      // TO-DO: Handling when `next` and `error` callback is completed.
    }
  });
}
```

**References:**

1. [Making a POST request](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request)
2. [Subscribing (Observable)](https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing)